# Unwanted apostrophe escapes in Err()

Tags: rust

Err() forcibly adds '\' escapes around apostrophes.  Searching finds [old complaints](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/3752) about this problem, but without apparent resolution.

How can I avoid these injected apostrophe escapes in Err strings?

```
fn bad() -> Result<(), String> {
    return Err("Can't avoid 'apostrophe' escapes.".to_string());
}

fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    println!("{}", "Can avoid 'apostrophe' escapes.".to_string());
    bad()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Results in:

```
Can avoid 'apostrophe' escapes.
Error: "Can\'t avoid \'apostrophe\' escapes."
```

Comment: `bad()?` for me gives `Error: "Can\'t avoid \'apostrophe\' escapes."` not merely `Can\'t avoid \'apostrophe\' escapes.`

Comment: @trentcl, thanks fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default logger for `main` returning `Result` is to use `Debug` to display the error. `Debug` on `String` always escapes `'`s.

If you want to change this behavior, you must handle the error yourself:

```rust
fn bad() -> Result<(), String> {
    return Err("Can't avoid 'apostrophe' escapes.".to_string());
}

fn my_main() -> Result<(), String> {
    println!("{}", "Can avoid 'apostrophe' escapes.".to_string());
    bad()?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = my_main() {
        println!("Error: {}", e);
    }
}
```